# Extract complex text pattern using SQL function

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400, textpattern

I need to extract a text pattern looking like this:

```
NN-NNN-NNNNNNNNN 
(2digit,minus, 3digits,minus,9digits)
```

from along text field. For example, specific field looks like this:

```
"fsadlk fasldkl jhkjfd khjfasd 11-333-878787618 hfsd uhjkfads"
```

I need to extract using sql function in the select line the 11-333-878787618. I'm using DB2 AS400 but any SQL function syntax will help.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, edit the question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Also add some sample table data and the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following may be useful in that regard; I can add the *extraction* as well, but I figured that might be understood already, after getting this far:

```
 create table patterns ( p varchar(65), find_at smallint )
 ;
 insert into  patterns values                                        
  ('fsadlk fasldkl jhkjfd khjfasd 11-333-878787618 hfsd uhjkfads',31)
 ,('weroiu 11-333-8787zz618 oiuwens snkdl osjlwhe'               ,00)
 ,('nm,sdj xhdgweufyen sndh 711-333-878787618 hfsd uhjkfads'     ,26)
 ,('nm,sdj xhdgweufyen sndh 11-333-8787876187 hfsd uhjkfads'     ,25)
 -- ....+....1....+....2....+....3....+....4....+....5....+....6.    
 ;
 select translate(p, '9', '0123456789', '9') as translated
     ,  smallint( locate( '99-999-999999999'              
                , translate(p, '9', '0123456789', '9') )  
                ) as located                              
     ,  find_at                                           
 from patterns                                            
 ; -- report from the above query follows:
TRANSLATED                                                         LOCATED   FIND_AT
fsadlk fasldkl jhkjfd khjfasd 99-999-999999999 hfsd uhjkfads            31        31
weroiu 99-999-9999zz999 oiuwens snkdl osjlwhe                            0         0
nm,sdj xhdgweufyen sndh 999-999-999999999 hfsd uhjkfads                 26        26
nm,sdj xhdgweufyen sndh 99-999-9999999999 hfsd uhjkfads                 25        25
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in SQL function that provide you with what you are trying to accomplish. I would suggest you have a look at [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0301stolze/0301stolze.html). It's an IBM post about how to do Regular Expressions on the iSeries DB2 SQL using User Defined Functions. And then the regex pattern to match the text would be:

```
\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d
```

It would be nice to use the proper Regular Expression pattern of:

```
\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{9}
```

But this regex function that IBM implemented is rather limited.

Comment: According to the documentation here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzregexp_like.htm the {n} modifiers should work at least at v7.1 and later. The real caveat is that the International Components for Unicode must be installed. I don't have those installed here, so I can't test this. The DB2 function you are looking for is `REGEXP_LIKE`.

Comment: BTW if you are looking for ICU for IBM i, it is option 39 of the operating system.

Comment: Thanks very much!  the regex is very powerful though i couldn't run it on my iSerious SQL environment